# Error talking to the Parse servers;please try again Windows 7

Tags: powershell, parse-platform, command-line

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7. I have downloaded the latest version of `Parse.exe` and `ParseConsole.exe` into a folder. When I run `ParseConsole.exe` and key in `parse new` command I'm getting this error:

> Error talking to the parse servers;please try again

When I key in the command `parse help` I'm getting info.

Am I missing something? Do I need to install any other plugins? How should I get it to run without errors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an error with a binary executable provided by a service trying to contact that particular service. I don't see how we could tell you what the problem is, nor is it programming related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an error with a binary executable provided by a service trying to contact that particular service. I don't see how we could tell you what the problem is, nor is it programming related

Comment: I'd second that and say the OP ought to support the question with feedback

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled a lot facing the same issue.

I was however able to solve the same.

1. Download the CLI from the [website](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/releases/tag/release_3.0.1).
2. Go [here](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) and check if you have same version of parse.exe as downloaded or else replace the older one with this.
3. copy both of the files ( parse.exe and parseconsole.exe) into c:\windows\system32 for 32 bit operating system and into c:\windows\syswow64 for 64 bit operating system
4. open windows power shell and run it as administrator , test all your commands.

It should be working fine now :)